# Having trouble decoding JSON Data in swift programming language

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, struct

I am having trouble decoding JSON Data in swift after using an API call. The application is actually a Pokedex application. I am having trouble; specifically on the line where I initialize the variable flavorTexts. I have found that I have received data from the URL (checkout https://pokeapi.co/) to view the pokemon data. When I print this data it comes out as x number of bytes. But after I decode it into flavorTexts and I print flavorTexts, nothing prints meaning flavorTexts has nothing in it. I have also found that the DispatchQueue function does not even begin as I can't any prints inside it do not print. Can someone help me? The third set of code is the data structs I have created for these API calls. For the API call I am having trouble with the structs used are: descriptions, items, and language.

The error I am getting is:

keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "lang", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "flavor_text_entries", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"lang\", intValue: nil) (\"lang\").", underlyingError: nil))

API CALL:

```
    func loadDescription () {
        url2 = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/" + (name) + "/"
        urlReal = URL(string: url2)
        print(url2!)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlReal) { (data1, response, error) in
            guard let data1 = data1 else {
                return
            }
            print(data1)
            do {
                //This is where I am having trouble
                let flavorTexts = try JSONDecoder().decode(descriptions.self, from: data1)
//                DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                    var fte = flavor_text_entry.flavor_text_entries
//                    for ft in fte {
//                        if ft.lang.name == "en" {
//                                self.textDescription.text = ft.flavor_text
//                                break
//                            }
//                        }
//                    }
                }
                catch {
                    error
                }
            }.resume()
        }
```

Data Structs:

```
import Foundation

struct PokemonListResults: Codable {
    let results: [PokemonListResult]
}

struct PokemonListResult: Codable {
    let name: String
    let url: String
}

struct PokemonResult: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let types: [PokemonTypeEntry]
}

struct PokemonTypeEntry: Codable {
    let slot: Int
    let type: PokemonType
}

struct PokemonType: Codable {
    let name: String
}

struct PokemonImage: Codable {
    let sprites: sprite
}

struct sprite: Codable {
    let front_default: String
}

struct descriptions: Codable {
    let flavor_text_entries: [items]
}

struct items: Codable {
    let flavor_text: String
    let lang: language
}

struct language: Codable {
    let name: String
}
```

Comment: To view the data that I am trying to reference go to this link (https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/bulbasaur/) or go to the poke API website (linked above) and in the input box input (pokemon-species/bulbasaur/). If you would like to view the data as JSON on the poke API website please check the view as JSON box at the bottom of the data field on the site. Thank You

Comment: Print the error in the catch and add it to the question also try to minimize the code by removing anything that isn’t relevant to your issue like the parts that work fine.

Comment: Yes I just realized that I didn't print the error correctly so I have printed and here is the return I am getting:  keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "lang", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "flavor_text_entries", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"lang\", intValue: nil) (\"lang\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Joakim Danielson. Thank You so much I printed the error and realized I just had to change the name lang in my struct to language so the decoder knew it was referencing language. I can now access the data

Comment: Hello @RohithRamanathan I came across your code and when I try to duplicate what you did I get this error ```Use of unresolved identifier 'flavor_text_entries'``` could you let me know where and how you defined flavor text entries? thank you

Comment: how are you able to saye let fte = flavor_text_entry.flavor_text if you are not defining flavor_text_entry nowhere?

Comment: Hello @diego, flavor_text_entry is defined in the data structs and is mapped to an array of items. Not sure why you are getting the error and would need more information to help out. I did resolve this problem some time ago and have moved on from this project so not sure how helpful I can be but I can try.